# Combined Partial Derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is in $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Does
$$
\frac{f(x_1+h, x_2+h)-f(x_1, x_2)}{h} \to \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}
$$
as $h \to 0$ ? I am led to believe this is true, but I can't quite see how to prove it. I would like to "break" $f(x_1+h, x_2+h)$ in two, but in general I don't see how this can be done.

Comment: You are only assuming your function to be continuous, the limit does necessarily exist.

Comment: @Mercy Typo ! Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgeMouselli Well I am familiar with derivatives of functions of several variables, but in this case $h \in \mathbb{R}$ and the left hand side of the limit is a number since $f$ is single-valued.

Comment: Im sorry to confuse you, in fact, you are right. I will answer the question below in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\ t\mapsto g(t)=f(x_1+t,x_2+t)$ is $C^1$, and we have
$$
g(t)=g(0)+tg'(0)+o(t)=f(x_1,x_2)+t\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)+t\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2)+o(t).
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_1+h,x_2+h)-f(x_1,x_2)}{h}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2).
$$

Answer (score 1):

The limit is correct, since $\Vert (x,y) - (x+h,y+h)\Vert = \Vert(h,h)\Vert = \sqrt2 h$, thus the limit will be (if existing)
$$\partial_x f(x,y) + \partial_y f(x,y)$$
Or, more concretely, it will be
$$\sqrt 2 \partial_{\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1)}f(x,y)$$
the directional derivative in direction $\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1)$.

Comment: Isn't this contradicting Mercy's answer ?

Comment: I think the factor $\sqrt{2}$ should not be there. We just have to take the dot product of $\nabla f$ with $(1,1)$, don't we ?

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The formula for the direction derivative is $Df(\vec{v}) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(p+t\vec{v})-f(p)}{t}$.  In OPs case, $v = (1,1)$, so his formula is correct.

Comment: @StevenGubkin note the factor in the direction vector. Your claim is incorrect; the factors cancel each other out.

Comment: @ALexR the heuristic is that $Df(v) \approx f(p+v) - f(p)$, so $Df(tv) \approx f(p+tv) - f(p)$, and thus (by linearity of $Df$), $tDf(v) \approx f(p+tv)-f(p)$, hence $Df(v) \approx \frac{f(p+tv)-f(p)}{t}$.  In the limit this approximation becomes exact.  For a formal proof, look (for example) at Multivariable Mathematics by Shifrin.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Now set $v = \frac1{\sqrt2} (1,1)$ (a normalized direction vector) and substitute $s = \sqrt2 t$ to arrive at precisely what I wrote.

Comment: Ah I see.  But it is misleading to say that "the limit will be a little different":  what the OP wrote is correct, and in fact agrees with what you have written.  Maybe the textbook you learned from unnecessarily restricted directional derivatives to unit vectors?  In any case, the final answer will be $Df(\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} 1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}1$.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Ah I see what the problem was. Fixed that. Regarding your assumption about my textbook: No, but I find it much nicer this way, since the behaviour, assuming the direction to be normalised, can be analysed on (small) balls of constant radius.

Comment: @AlexR the huge disadvantage of directional derivatives restricted to only unit vectors, is that the directional derivative fails to be a linear operator of the direction vector when defined in this way.

Comment: @StevenGubkin In that context I agree.